# Processing: Snake Game Movement Logic

Tags: arraylist, processing

the movement speed of my snake is doubled everytime I eat an apple. I can't seem to figure out what's causing it. Also, another thing that's confusing me is whenever I call a background() and then call a drawgrid right below it, the grid appears and disappears quickly at the start of the game then never gets drawn again. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here's the code:

```
  class Sprite {
  float x;
  float y;
  float [] dx = {0, 0, 20, -20};//up, down, right, left
  float [] dy = {20, -20, 0, 0};//up, down, right, left

  void update() {
    x += dx[dir];
    y += dy[dir];
  }
}

class Body extends Sprite {

  void render() {

    pushMatrix();
    stroke(255);
    fill(0);
    rect(x, y, bSize, bSize);
    popMatrix();
  }

  void update() {
    super.update();
    if (Direction.equals("up")) {
      dir = 1;
    } else if (Direction.equals("down")) {
      dir = 0;
    } else if (Direction.equals("right")) {
      dir = 2;
    } else if (Direction.equals("left")) {
      dir = 3;
    }

    if (dist(x, y, applex*bSize, appley*bSize) < 10) {
      add = true;
      applex = ceil(random(0, 38));
      appley = ceil(random(0, 38));
    }
  }
}
int w = 50;
int h = 50;
float bSize;
color fillColor;
String Direction;
int dir = 2; //starting at the "right" direction
ArrayList<Body> sBody;
float applex;
float appley;
float prevX;
float prevY;

boolean add = false;

void setup() {

  size(801, 801);
  smooth();
  //frameRate(12);
  applex = ceil(random(0, 38));
  appley = ceil(random(0, 38));
  bSize = 20;
  prevX = -5;
  prevY = -5;
  fillColor = color(0);
  Direction = "right";
  sBody = new ArrayList<Body>();
  Body b = new Body();
  sBody.add(b);
}

void draw() {
  if (add) {
    Body b = new Body();
    sBody.add(b);
    add = false;
  }

  if ((frameCount%5)==0) {
    //background(255);
    drawGrid();
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    rect(applex*bSize, appley*bSize, 20, 20);
    for (Body t : sBody) {
      if (prevX > -1 && prevY > -1) {
        t.x = prevX;
        t.y = prevY;
      }
      t.render();
      t.update();
      prevX = t.x;
      prevY = t.y;
    }
  }
}

void keyPressed() {
  if (key == CODED) {

    if (Direction.equals("right") || Direction.equals("left")) {
      if (keyCode == UP) {
        Direction = "up";
      }
      if (keyCode == DOWN) {
        Direction = "down";
      }
    }

    if (Direction.equals("up") || Direction.equals("down")) {
      if (keyCode == RIGHT) {
        Direction = "right";
      }
      if (keyCode == LEFT) {
        Direction = "left";
      }
    }
  }
}

void drawGrid() {

  for (int i =  0; i < height; i += 20) {
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j += 20) {
      pushMatrix();
      fill(200);
      stroke(255);
      rect(i, j, bSize, bSize);
      popMatrix();
    }
  }
}


////end of code////
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put `frameRate(5)` in your setup you will see why that happens, plus you will not need the `if ((frameCount%5)==0)`. Essentially as many Bodys you have, the whole snake skips so many blocks! This happens because of the way you built your for loop, which essentially renders the blocks in such a way that the last block is the head of the snake.

If I may propose a better solution. The only block you really need to update is the head of the snake which I suggest to be `sBody.get(0)`. The rest of the blocks just need to have the previous position, but you must be careful that each cell gets the position of the previous one! Here's the solution:

```
for (Body t : sBody) {
  if (t == sBody.get(0)) {
    // if its the first element (the head) store its 
    // position in prevX,prevY and update it afterwards
    prevX = t.x;
    prevY = t.y;
    t.update();
  } else {
    // otherwise for other blocks, since we are 
    // using prevX, prevY for the previous block
    // we need to store the current position
    // of this block to give it back to prevX, prevY
    float tpX = t.x;
    float tpY = t.y;
    t.x = prevX;
    t.y = prevY;
    prevX = tpX;
    prevY = tpY;
  }
  t.render();
}
```

The grid problem I don't see in my case, it's probably because you are using that `if ((frameCount%5)==0)` line...

Answer (score 2):

Your logic has a few problems.

Take a look at this loop:

```
for (Body t : sBody) {
      if (prevX > -1 && prevY > -1) {
        t.x = prevX;
        t.y = prevY;
      }
      t.render();
      t.update();
      prevX = t.x;
      prevY = t.y;
 }
```

Notice how you're calling `update()` on **every** `Body` Object in your List. This causes the snake to move for every segment, which is why it gets faster when it gets longer. To fix **that** problem, you need to only call `update()` on the **head** of the snake, and then loop through the rest of the segments to have them follow the head.

But that's not your only problem. Also notice that after this loop exits, `prevX` and `prevY` will hold the value of the **last** `Body` Object in your `sBody` List. Then the next time you loop through, you're setting position of the **head** of the snake to that position. This doesn't make any sense, and it causes your snake to "steer" from the last segment instead of the head.

Your third problem is: You're also setting the value of `prevX` and `prevY` **after** you update them, which again causes your snake to behave incorrectly.

So to fix all of those problems, you need to do a few things:

- Only `update()` the head of the snake.
- Set `prevX` and `prevY` before each loop instead of moving the head to the end.
- Only loop through the **rest** of the snake to have it follow the head.
- Use temporary variable so `prevX` and `prevY` are set to the values that `t.x` and `t.y` held **before** you updated them.

In the end, your loop should look something like this:

```
    //only move the head
    sBody.get(0).update();

    //set prevX and prevY to the head's position
    prevX =  sBody.get(0).x;
    prevY =  sBody.get(0).y;

    for (Body t : sBody) {

      //render ever piece, including the head
      t.render();

      //but don't move the head again
      if (t == sBody.get(0)) {
        continue;
      }

      //store the position before you change it
      float tempX = t.x;
      float tempY = t.y;

      //change the position
      t.x = prevX;
      t.y = prevY;

      //prevX and prevY hold the t.x and t.y values **before** you updated them
      prevX = tempX;
      prevY = tempY;
    }
```

Also, it's worth noting that this would probably be much easier to implement using a 2D array instead. Oh, and your calls to `pushMatrix()` and `popMatrix()` are unnecessary, since you aren't actually modifying the matrix.

Comment: Thank you so much! You reply was very helpful.